# Мне нужно получить код страницы или скачать html файл автоматически. Проблема - сайт понимает, что запросы автоматические и выдает капчу

Tags: html, запрос

Как можно это обойти? Любыми способами. Хочется именно не взломать капчу, а обойти само ее генерирование - то есть чтобы она вообще не появлялась.

Мне удалось это сделать на Mac Os с помощью простенькой проги в Автоматоре - он скачивает 1,5 тыс. страниц, не вызывая подозрений у сайта)

Но мне нужно найти, как сделать подобное на Windows

[image: Полученная капча]

Comment: Если сайт не хочет, чтобы с него получали информацию скриптами, почему вы пытаетесь её получить против его воли? Это всё равно как спросить, «человек не даёт мне сигарету, как её отобрать?».